# Expanding textbox stopping page breaks in PDF conversion

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, page-break

I have a simple report that has an image and a textbox within the body (a rectangle).  The textbox is set to 'Allow Height to Increase'.  The rectangle is set to 'Page Break After'.

Normally this works fine if the contents of the textbox span a few lines.  However, when the textbox expands over multiple pages the Page Break is ignored.  This only happens when exporting to PDF, yet works as expected in Preview mode.

I'm hoping someone has some insight into this behaviour or can recommend an alternative page structure that will achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the Rectangles property

> ***kept contents together on a single page***

in a parent Rectangle object, this will always keep items together where possible.
You could also set page setup settings (margins, gutters, printable page size...) to make sure that they are not affects on exported PDF document.